# Alternate for showForm method in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am converting my application from spring mvc 2 to spring mvc 3. I am using `showForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, BindException errors)` [given in doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html#showForm%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20org.springframework.validation.BindException%29). I could not find its alternative in Spring mvc 3.

Comment: Assuming your are doing formhandling in your application, here is an [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-and-jsr303-valid-example/) of how it is done in Spring 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return to same view your model attributes and it will work good.